# Do dielectric materials have electrical retentivity?

Tags: electrostatics, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Magnetic materials have (magnetic) retentivity. Do dielectric materials also have electrical retentivity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if processed appropriately- as follows.

There is a type of high-performance microphone called a *condenser microphone* in which a thin plastic membrane which flexes when hit by sound waves serves as one plate of a capacitor (or "condenser"), with the other plate fixed in position. A constant voltage is impressed across the plate pair by an external power supply; when sound waves hit the flexible plate, it moves alternately closer and farther apart from the fixed plate. Since changing the spacing between the plates changes the capacitance of the capacitor, current flows into and out of the capacitor as it flexes back and forth. That AC current flow is picked off the capacitor and amplified as the analog output of the microphone.

There are special polymer dielectric films which can be *poled* by applying a strong electric field to them while hot, and then allowing them to cool with the field still on. Once cooled, the dielectric polymer permanently retains the dipole orientations impressed upon it by the external field and now it can serve as a condenser microphone element that does not require an external voltage source in order to function.

This is one form of an *electret microphone* as used in cell phones, handheld radio sets, and the like.